# Save vb.net HTML in UTF8 or Unicode

Tags: vb.net, file, unicode, utf-8, save

Hello and good afternoon, i am in development of my project long story short i need to save my html base page with UTF8 or Unicode

```
 Dim y As String
    Dim UTF8encoding() As Byte, MyEncoder As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(TRUE)
    y = (html code should be here will be under)
    Dim utf8 As New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim utf8EmitBOM As New UTF8Encoding(True)
    Dim code As String = y
    Path = "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\invoice.html"

    Try
        Dim my_write As System.IO.StreamWriter
        my_write = IO.File.CreateText(path)
        my_write.write(utf8EmitBOM.GetPreamble())
        UTF8encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, MyEncoder.GetBytes(y))
        my_write.WriteLine(code)
        my_write.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

HTML

```
 <html>
  <style>
   table, th, td 
   { border: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body><center><b>
   <font size=20>Family Butcher</font></br></br></br><center><b>
   <font size =4>164 Battersea Bridge Road London SW11 3AW</center></font><center><b>
   <font size =4>Tel:  Mob:</center></font><center><b>
   <font size =4>VAT No: 835522334</center></br></font></br>
   <table Border = 3 WIDTH=610 align=left></br><tr>
   <th colspan=3 align = left>To: " & txto & " <br/>
   <br/>Date:  <br/><br/>Invoice nº    <br/></th></tr>
   <td WIDTH = 100 HEIGHT=40><center><b>Quantity </b></td>
   <td WIDTH = 400><center><b>Description</b></td><td><center>
   <b>Value</b>   </br></p>
   </body></html>
```

At the moment i do not know how to save the file in either unicode or utf8 and then i cannot open the html file without the symbols "Â" Thanks for any support

Comment: Have you tried File.WriteAllText ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @neolist I love you... T_T, basicly i was miss reading and applying the file write all , thank you soo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use **File.WriteAllText** - [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to specify encoding, so you can accomplish your goal with just one line of code, for example:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, code, Encoding.UTF8)
```